# How to calculate reactance in a circuit full of coils?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

I've seen plenty of examples on how to calculate reactance with a combination of a coil, capacitor and ohmic resistor. However, I'm not sure how to find the overall reactance in a circuit that would look the following. We have AC and 3 coils where one coil is parallel to a series of the two other coils. Now I have 2 ideas.

1. Does $ \frac{1}{X}= \frac{1}{X_1} + \frac{1}{X_2+X_3}$ for the parallel connection work?
2. The other one would be to calculate the overall inductance of the coils, $\frac{1}{L}= \frac{1}{L_1} + \frac{1}{L_2+L_3}$ and then from there use the usual $X=2\pi fL$.
   Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Reactances in series add like resistors in series, in parallel they combine like resistors in parallel.

Series:  $X_{equiv} = X_1 + X_2$

Parallel: $X_{equiv} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{X_1}+\frac{1}{X_2}}$

If inductive reactance, then it has a j operator to indicate its impedance at the particular steady-state frequency has angle of 90 degrees.  If capacitive reactance it has a -j operator (-90 degrees).

Combine the two that are in series first, then you will be left with 2 in parallel that you can combine.